# Rails - Adding a value to the Active Association build before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add the `user_id` to a build association before save. I have a complex form with two models.

This code is in my `new_order` method:

```
@customer_order = CustomerOrder.new(:order_amt => @mailer.full_price, 
                                    :years   => @mailer.years, 
                                    :magazine_id => @mailer.magazine_id, 
                                    :mailer_id => @mailer.id,   
                                    :source => 'Mailer', 
                                    :lead_id => @mailer.lead.id, 
                                    :new_or_renewal => 'N', 
                                    :user_id  => current_user.id) 

@customer_order.payments.build
```

The association is saved perfectly and exactly the way I want. Then when I click to save the form, in the create method I want to add the `current_user_id` to the payment model. I am trying not to persist it in the form as I heard that was a bad practice.

```
@customer_order.save
```

So right before the `@customer_order.save`, I want to add:

```
payment.user_id => current_user_id
```

Comment: build = create + save.
simply use create method first.

Comment: @weezing a bit off. `create` = `build` + `save`

Comment: @D-side yup, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@customer_order.payments.create(user_id: current_user_id)
@customer_order.save
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a callback for just this requirement, and it is called - very simply - `before_save`

[before_save documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/before_save)

Essentially, in your model, you can define certain steps to be taken before an active-record is saved.

Read more about callbacks [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)

To quote:

> During the normal operation of a Rails application, objects may be
>   created, updated, and destroyed. Active Record provides hooks into
>   this object life cycle so that you can control your application and
>   its data.
>
> Callbacks allow you to trigger logic before or after an alteration of
>   an object's state.